# What does "[26]USER" mean in an IIS FTP log?

Tags: ftp, logging

In our IIS FTP log we have an entry that includes this:

> [26]USER

Where can I look up to see the meaning of this?  Particularly the number in the square brackets?

Answer (score 2):

It appears

- 26 = connection ID
- USER = FTP Command.

That'll teach me to post before properly looking :-)

Answer (score 1):

More information would be VERY useful:
Which operating system are you running?
Which ftp daemon are you running?

If you are on a Linux with a rpm based package manager you could try something like

```
rpm -qa | grep -i ftp
```

to find out which ftp packages you have installed.

Read the man page and or web page of the ftp daemon in use.

Comment: Sorry this is an IIS log - I've discovered what this means - see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [Wikipedia Article about FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) to learn the basics of the protocol. Fort further information you can have a look the [documentation of the File Transfer Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2228).

FTP is dialog based, which means that the server and client are sending in turns information and answers to requests. `USER <username>` is the command for authenticating at the server with the given username.